# Create pagination as well as number per page selection on PHP image gallery

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I've got a simple PHP image gallery where the PHP reads data from a MySQL database and organizes and links each one to a larger version. It works well but places too many images on the page.

I'm hoping someone can show me how to first split the images into multiple pages, as well as create navigation for users through the pages.

If it's possible, I would also like the user to be able select how many images should be displayed per page, with a default of, say, 16.

Below is my current gallery's code:

```
<?php
$mysql_link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");   
mysql_select_db("new_arrivals_imgs") or die("Could not select database");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT `imgURL`,`imgTitle` FROM `images` ".
                     "ORDER BY `imgDate` DESC") or die(mysql_error());

if(!$query) {
 echo "Cannot retrieve information from database.";
} else {
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  echo "<li><a href='new_arrivals_img/".$row['imgURL'].
           "' class='gallery' title='".$row['imgTitle'].
           "'><img src='new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/".
           $row['imgURL']."'></a></li>";
 }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add LIMIT to the end of your query string.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `imgURL`,`imgTitle` FROM `images` ".
"ORDER BY `imgDate` DESC LIMIT " . $limit * $curPage . ", $limit") or die(mysql_error());
```

The first part of limit is where to start and the second is the length.

`$limit` can be set by a select box or user text and `$curPage` can be carried through url parameters.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Comment: Would that not make the number of images per page static? I want the user to be able to decide how many photos per page, with a default value. Is that possible?

Comment: ok ok, I think I read your response wrong. Could you give me more detail though? Explain `$curPage` a bit more perhaps?

Comment: $curPage stores the current page the user is on. You can keep track of this with url parameters (?curPage=3) and access it via $_GET['curPage'] and assign $curPage = $_GET['curPage']. $limit would be the amount of pictures you wanted to show per page. As $curPage changes the start of the mySQL LIMIT statement (offset) changes. For example LIMIT for page 1 would be 16 * 1, 16. For page 2 it would be 16 * 2, 16.

Answer (score 0):

If you wind up with many pages (i.e. 100+) you might want to look at "logarithmic" page navigation, as described here:

[How to do page navigation for many, many pages? Logarithmic page navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7835752/999120)